# Sum the odd and even indices of an array separately - Perl

Tags: perl

I have an array of 11 elements. Where I want to sum the odd elements including the first and last elements as one scalar and the evens as another.

This is my code I am trying to use map adding 2 to each index to achieve the result but I think I have got it wrong.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

print 'Enter the 11 digiet serial number: ';
chomp( my @barcode = //, <STDIN> );

my @sum1 = map { 2 + $_ } $barcode[1] .. $barcode[11];
my $sum1 = sum Dumper( \@sum1 );

# sum2 = l2 + l4 + l6 + r8 + r10;
printf "{$sum1}";
```

What is a good way to achieve this?

Comment: This is a "Debug my code for me" question, which is off-topic here. Can you maybe walk us through your code and explain what the `map` statement is supposed to do? Especially, what is `$barcode[1]..$barcode[11]` supposed to do? Look at the case of `$barcode[1]=99` and `$barcode[11]=0`.

Comment: normally array of 11 elements, elements are indexed from 0 to 10 ; `@barcode[0..10]` note the `@` prefix to get a sliced array

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sum of even/odd indicies (what you asked for, but not what you want<sup>[1]</sup>):

```
use List::Util qw( sum );   # Or: sub sum { my $acc; $acc += $_ for @_; $acc }

my $sum_of_even_idxs = sum grep { $_ % 2 == 0 } 0..$#nums;
my $sum_of_odd_idxs  = sum grep { $_ % 2 == 1 } 0..$#nums;
```

Sum of even/odd values (what you also asked for, but not what you want<sup>[1]</sup>):

```
use List::Util qw( sum );   # Or: sub sum { my $acc; $acc += $_ for @_; $acc }

my $sum_of_even_vals = sum grep { $_ % 2 == 0 } @nums;
my $sum_of_odd_vals  = sum grep { $_ % 2 == 1 } @nums;
```

Sum of values at even/odd indexes (what you appear to want):

```
use List::Util qw( sum );   # Or: sub sum { my $acc; $acc += $_ for @_; $acc }

my $sum_of_vals_at_even_idxs = sum @nums[ grep { $_ % 2 == 0 } 0..$#nums ];
my $sum_of_vals_at_odd_idxs  = sum @nums[ grep { $_ % 2 == 1 } 0..$#nums ];
```

Given that you know how many elements you have, you could use the following:

```
use List::Util qw( sum );   # Or: sub sum { my $acc; $acc += $_ for @_; $acc }

my $sum_of_vals_at_even_idxs = sum @nums[0,2,4,6,8,10];
my $sum_of_vals_at_odd_idxs  = sum @nums[1,3,5,7,9];
```

---

1. I included these in case someone needing these lands on this Q&A.

Comment: You could shrink your two greps to, in order `grep { $_ % 2 }` and `gerep { ! ($_ %  2)}`

Comment: 1) I purposefully didn't for symmetry (which produces clearer code). 2) While it does reduce the number of tokens for odds, it actually increases the number of tokens for evens.

Answer (score 5):

Add up values at odd and at even indices

```
perl -wE'@ary = 1..6;  
    for (0..$#ary) { $_ & 1 ? $odds += $ary[$_] : $evens += $ary[$_] }; 
    say "odds: $odds, evens: $evens"
'
```

Note for tests: with even indices (0,2,4) we have (odd!) values (1,3,5), in this (`1..6`) example

Comment: nice use of ternary operator to assign odds/evens.. I also have posted an answer for this..

Answer (score 4):

You can use the fact that the `?:` operator is assignable

```
print 'Enter the 11 digiet serial number: ';
chomp( my @barcode = //, <STDIN> );

my $odd = 0;
my $even = 0;
for (my $index = 0; $index < @barcode; $index++) {
    ($index % 2 ? $even : $odd) += $barcode[$index];
}
```

This works by indexing over `@barcode` and taking the mod 2 of the index, ie dividing the index by 2 and taking the remainder, and if the remainder is 1 adding that element of `@barcode` to `$even` otherwise to `$odd`.

That looks strange until you remember that arrays are 0 based so your first number of the barcode is stored in `$barcode[0]` which is an even index.

Answer (score 3):

`chomp( my @barcode = //, <STDIN> );` presumably was supposed to have a `split` before the `//`?

`@barcode` will have all the characters in the line read, including the newline.  The chomp will change the final element from a newline to an empty string.

Better to chomp first so you just have your digits in the array:

```
chomp(my $barcode = <STDIN>);
my @barcode = split //, $barcode;
```

Answer (score 3):

Another Perl, if the string is of length 11 and contains only digits

```
$ perl -le ' $_="12345678911"; s/(.)(.)|(.)$/$odd+=$1+$3;$even+=$2/ge; print "odd=$odd; even=$even" '
odd=26; even=21

$
```

with different input

```
$ perl -le ' $_="12121212121"; s/(.)(.)|(.)$/$odd+=$1+$3;$even+=$2/ge; print "odd=$odd; even=$even" '
odd=6; even=10

$
```